# Access callback parameters called by async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have a function that returns a callback containing some data, how can I run it with async and access the data when async completes?

Example:

```
var async = require('async');

function provisionServer(server, callback) {
  return callback('abcd');
}

getServerQueue(function (err, servers) {
  async.each(servers, provisionServer, function (err) {
    if (err)
      logger.error("[async provisionServer] " + err);
    else {
      console.log("How can I get the 'abcd' from the provisionServer callback?");
      async.each(servers, dequeueServer, function (err,result) {
      if (err)
        logger.error("[async dequeueServer] " + err);
      else {

      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `async.map` instead of `async.each`:

```
function provisionServer(server, callback) {
  return callback(null, 'abcd');
}

getServerQueue(function (err, servers) {
  async.map(servers, provisionServer, function (err, results) {
    if (err)
      logger.error("[async provisionServer] " + err);
    else {
      console.dir(results);
      async.each(servers, dequeueServer, function (err, result) {
      if (err)
        logger.error("[async dequeueServer] " + err);
      else {

      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a little confusion around the two callbacks at play here.

Here is how it can be broken down:

```
var list_of_stuff = [1,2,3];
async.each(list_of_stuff, iterator_fn, error_fn);
```

The first param is the list of stuff you want iterated over. The second is the iterator function you want to call per item. Note that this function takes in as parameters the item of interest and a callback which that invocation of the iterator will use to signal completion, and looks like so:

```
function iterator_fn(item, iterator_callback) {...}
```

The next function passed in is the error_fn, and this is just a plain ol error handler:

```
function error_fn(error) {...}
```

Comment: Woah, my answer got cut off.. regardless - you can use async.parallel to return a list of results from the parallell run functions.